# Bootstrap Datepicker with multiple months

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

Is there any bootstrap datepicker available that supports displaying multiple months? There is an option in jquery-ui datepicker: `numberOfMonths`.

I need something like this: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/multiple-calendars.html

Comment: I'm looking for the same control. Did you find anything helpful?

Comment: I'm using jquery.ui.datepicker.js now :)

Answer (score 0):

two months in a single view

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2
        });
    } );
</script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```