# How to show multiple months in bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to show two months in a single view of bootstrap-datepicker. Please find the sample code from the following link.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Kz2sW/234/)

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507771/bootstrap-datepicker-with-multiple-months

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look to the following links :

https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker

http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20130906-0309

hope this is helps

Answer (score -1):

This will show two months in a single view :

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2
        });
    } );
</script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: It does reflect nothing on bootstrap-datepicker.. Did you use any other date picker?

Comment: I think he refers to jQuery UI datepicker