# Show all months in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am new to bootstrap. I Want to show full Year calendar(inline) in bootstrap like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pawankullu/odau1r41/12/) (JqueryUI)

I have tried this as :

```
<div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker12').datepicker({

    });
});
```

But this will show only one month as expected.

How can I Show full year calendar in bootstrap?
I am using Bootstrap v3.1.1

Comment: Is it supported in the documentation? If not...find a plugin that does

Comment: I do not find it in its documentation. ;(

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507771/bootstrap-datepicker-with-multiple-months