# Make JQueryUI Datepicker Responsive

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have to show all the months(12) of a particular year simultaneously like .[yearly calendar(**4X3**)](http://jsfiddle.net/pawankullu/odau1r41/12/)

I am working on bootstrap. In bootstrap I could not do this as I asked this Qus [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663169/show-all-months-in-bootstrap-datepicker), but did not got any ans.

So I moved to JqueryUI and it is working fine. Jquery Code is:

```
$("#dvCalendar").datepicker({
            defaultDate: new Date((parseInt(year, 10) - 1), 12, 31),
            numberOfMonths: [4, 3],
            changeMonth: false,
            changeYear: false,
            duration: 'fast',
            stepMonths: 0,
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                --DO STUFF
            }
        });
```

Now the problem is with small devices.

How can I make this yearly calendar responsive for all devices using media queries or something else?

Comment: You can use: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/datepicker/

Comment: I can't use that for some reasons ;(